# Does over smiling falls under girlish in India?

Tags: conversations, india, gender, non-verbal-communication

While staying with a group of friends, colleagues or with a single individual, is it okay to have smiling face always during normal conversations or while wishing others such as good morning etc.,

Most of the people who interact won't say anything for and against it. But some frank people ask that **why are you feeling shy?**.

Actually, I don't feel shy while talking, but it's my habit to keep smiling face when people are around me and while normal conversation.

Is there need to smile less during talk or wish or its okay to continue with a smile?

I am a young male from India.

Comment: I think the answer(s) to this question, if there are any that are not purely opinion-based, will benefit from a location tag. Where do you live? Acceptance of smiles varies with countries and cultures, among other factors.

Comment: I edited accordingly

Comment: The question is a bit unclear as it does not address what type of smile you usually wear. The type of smile invokes an emotional response in others which may or may not be effective, given the situation. For an interesting read (and view, there's some videos in in too), see http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20170407-why-all-smiles-are-not-the-same

Comment: You're asking about smiling in general, but the response you get from others (asking why you're **shy**) suggests that you're smiling _in lieu of_ (expected) verbal interaction. This is considerably different than just asking whether it's okay to smile.

Comment: I smile to show my welcoming-ness and mostly smile just out of courtesy. I don't know why other people receive it as shy ...

Comment: Did you try asking people why do they make this remark?

Comment: I think smiling is an interesting aspect of interpersonal communication. Maybe you can reword your question to make it less opinion-based, so it can be reopend?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket I generally feel offend and does not ask instantaneously. But when asked to my closest ones, I came to know that they also don't know why it's falling under shy category. But they suggested me to maintain serious face like MEN instead of smiling face.

Comment: From experience I came to know loosely that people generally feel that MEN should mostly possess serious face and if a men smiles more, it may fall under shy category or girlish. So I am confused about smiling more in front of people.

Comment: Like with all things, Smiling just to have a smile can come off unnatural... seem odd... It's better to go with the dynamics of the conversation rather than forcing a smile on your face just to be polite. There is nothing wrong with smiling, but smiling all day can make you seem like an air-head. At least in western/american culture.

Comment: @hanugm specifying the question to be about men only does not make the question itself any less opinion-based. You could slightly reword it to be more about *smiling etiquette in india*. That would help ;)

Answer (score 3):

Smiling naturally and smiling on purpose has some distinct differences. It´s very hard to fake a honest natural smile. Most people will [detect the difference](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2015/apr/10/psychology-empathy-distinguish-fake-genuine-smiles), at least subconsciously and to them you will probably feel a bit artificial and unsecure.

So unless you work in customer-service, I´d suggest to forget about smiling and just let your body do what it does naturally.

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I am not proficient in Indian culture, so this may be different locally. My viewpoint comes from western culture as well as general human psychology</sub>

Comment: Although this might be completely true, an alternative could be that the "shy" remark was made because the other person expected a response and all they got was a (possibly genuine) smile.

Comment: @Imus: What makes you think that? OP states nothing that indicates that sort of behavior. I try to keep my answers in the premises of what OP gives as information.

Comment: My comment was meant to show how little we know about the actual situation. Someone told OP that he gives the impression of being shy. We don't know what situation OP was in or what made that person tell that observation. We only know that OP assumed it was because he was putting on a smile all the time. It's impossible to tell if that assumption was right. I did mean it when I said that your answer might be completely true though. All I'm saying is that we can't tell anything meaningful about it with the little information OP gave us about the situation.

Comment: @Imus: I can. Always smiling will look strange anyways. OP asked specifically about that. This is very answerable ....

Comment: Note that he did not ask why people though he was shy, he just gave that as tangential information. He asked if always smiling is ok!